# Automatic feature selection - Sklearn.feature_selection

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have two datasets a train and test data. train.shape = (307511, 122) and test.shape = (48744, 121). both these data sets contain these dtype: int32, float64 and object.

I did hot encoding to convert objects to either float or int dtype.

```
train = pd.get_dummies(train)
test = pd.get_dummies(test)
print('Train dummies shape: {}'.format(train.shape))
print('Test dummies shape: {}'.format(test.shape))
```

*I got these results from the code above:*

```
Train dummies shape: (307511, 246)
Test dummies shape: (48744, 242)
```

The shape has changed thus HotEncoding has succeeded. But now the problem I am facing is that When I try to train and test my data i get this error:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')
```

These are my imports:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel 
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
```

Please help

Comment: This is a bit off topic but the number of features in your training set is slightly more than your test set. This will eventually result in an error thrown by your model when you predict on your test set. As for the error you present, where in the code is it occurring?

Comment: This occurred when I tried to automatically select the best features

Comment: X_new = SelectKBest(chi2, k=2).fit_transform(X, y)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
train.as_matrix().astype(np.float)
test.as_matrix().astype(np.float)
```

Comment: This does not show me an error but now I think my data contains infinity numbers of type float. Thanks for the code it solved one of the problems